# vmware hardware version info from Guest OS

Tags: linux, vmware

i was looking if there is a option with vmware tools command or any other where i can get the vmware hardware version of the guest OS, 
currently i have tried is vmware-toolbox-cmd -v which gives the vmware tools version, but not the hardware version, this is very much required for me as one of the application system has given a pre-requisite to get the vmware hardware to be on version 10 before the installation. Currently i have access only to the guest OS no access to the ESX servers.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick for me:

```
# cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

case $( dmidecode | grep -A4 "BIOS Information" | fgrep "Address:" | awk '{print $2}' ) in
    "0xE8480" ) echo "ESX 2.5" ;;
    "0xE7C70" ) echo "ESX 3.0" ;;
    "0xE7910" ) echo "ESX 3.5" ;;
    "0xE7910" ) echo "ESX 4"   ;;
    "0xEA550" ) echo "ESX 4U1" ;;
    "0xEA2E0" ) echo "ESX 4.1" ;;
    "0xE72C0" ) echo "ESX 5"   ;;
    "0xE9AB0" ) echo "ESX 5.1" ;;
    "0xEA0C0" ) echo "ESX 5.1 (older)" ;;
    "0xEA050" ) echo "ESX 5.5" ;;
    "0xE9A40" ) echo "ESX 6.0" ;;
    * ) echo "Unknown version for address:"
    dmidecode | grep -A4 "BIOS Information" | fgrep "Address:" | awk '{print $2}'
    ;;
esac
```

Example output:

```
# ./test.sh
ESX 5.1
```

Note that I've only tested this on centos 6.x and 7.

EDIT: added ESX 5.5, 6.0 and an older version of 5.1. [source](http://virtwo.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/which-vsphere-version-is-my-vm-running.html)